# @GeneratedValue doesnt generate value although i have sequence defined in oracle sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have problem with this authentication code

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        UserInfo userInfo= new UserInfo();
        userInfo.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
        userInfo.setEmail(userDto.getEmail());
        userInfo.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userDto.getPassword()));
        userInfo.setRole(userDto.getRole());
        userRepository.save(userInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public UserInfo findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class UserDto {
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "userdetails")
public class UserInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "seq_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_id",sequenceName = "seq_id",allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    /.../
}
```

All the data is correctly stored in UserDto as i checked with logging but there is a problem with id in UserInfo. Im using Oracle SQL and have created sequence that will increment value, but when i use it as follows with @GeneratedValue and @SequenceGenerator it returns me an error

```
[Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [ORA-04098: trigger 'LOCALADMIN.USERDETAILS_ID_TRG' is not correct; revalidation failed
] [insert into userdetails (email,password,role,username,id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into userdetails (email,password,role,username,id) values (?,?,?,?,?)]] with root cause
```

I tried using different strategies in @GeneratedValue
1)For GenerationType.AUTO i recieve error ORA-02289 sequence doesnt exists
2)For GenerationType.Identity i recieve

```
could not execute statement [ORA-04098: trigger 'LOCALADMIN.USERDETAILS_ID_TRG' is not correct; revalidation failed
] [insert into userdetails (email,password,role,username,id) values (?,?,?,?,default)]; SQL [insert into userdetails (email,password,role,username,id) values (?,?,?,?,default)]] with root cause
```

Comment: Have you created the trigger USERDETAILS_ID_TRG? It is incorrect, thus everything fails. You should either fix it or drop it. This is in the database, not in your code, though perhaps your code has generated the trigger at some point.

Comment: @ewramner yeah it was the problem now it works, tysm!